# href to different page on website doesnt work the way i want it to

Tags: html, css

I want to add a picture on top of a button that leads to a diffent page on the web. And i want the picture to act like a button aswell. and when you hover over the button or the picture it needs to be able to do something like its one button.

```
          <a class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectForum()">Forum</a>
      <img class="forum" src="img/forum.png" />
      <a class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectStore()">Store</a>
      <img class="cart" src="img/cart.png" />
```

I think i need to do it like this and then add some sort of css to it but i really dont know what i need to add. This is my first try on this and i dont know a lot about html and css, but i can alwasy use google.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to make your picture a clickable link you need to surround it in  tags.

```
<a href=“your-link.html><img src=“your-photo-path.png”></a>
```

That way, you will have both a button AND a picture. Instead of clickable text, it will be a photo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to be part of your link you have to put it inside the < a > tag.
The following would be a basic example :

```
 <a class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectForum()">
      <img class="forum" src="img/forum.png" /><br>
      Forum
    </a>

    <a class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectStore()">
      <img class="cart" src="img/cart.png" /><br>
      Store
    </a>
```

as it is the < a > tags will give you a cursor on hover no need of the class

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `<img>` tag in the `<a>` tag:

```
<a class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectForum()">
  Forum
  <img class="forum" src="img/forum.png" />
</a>
<a class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectStore()">
  Store
  <img class="cart" src="img/cart.png" />
</a>
```

As a further improvement you can use the [`figure` and `figcaption` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) to represent an image caption.

Comment: Thanks i got the pictures next to the text. And how do i manipuilate it to show outside of the box and on top?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need the add href="" tag at the button. And if you want the click your photo like a link, you need to add the photo inside of the your button.

```
<a href="" class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectForum()">
<img class="forum" src="img/forum.png" />Forum
</a>

<a href="" class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectStore()">
<img class="cart" src="img/cart.png" />Store
</a>
```